# Approved & Published Google OAuth consent screen still gives "This app isn't verified" Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I submitted changes to my OAuth consent screen.

- Name change
- logo update,
- 2 new scopes
- domain change

Google contacted me to send them a video that show how I would be using the 2 new scopes. I did this and after that they approved everything. The verification status changed to "Published" and all domains and scopes have a green tick next to them.

I can see the logo & name change when I do a normal login. When I request the new scopes on the screen where it is needed I still see the "This app isn't verified".

I have confirmed that I am sending only the scopes in the consent screen.

1. openid
2. profile
3. email
4. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
5. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

I replied to the emails that google sent me to ask if there is still something that needs to be approved, they just reply and ask for a video. It looks like an automated response, but then I send them another video.

What more needs to be done to get the app verified? I did go through all their documentation.

[image: Verification Status]

[image: Consent Screen]

[image: Error screen]

Comment: usually it doesn't disappear immediately, but what I would probably do is write support just in case :)

Comment: @pievis thanks, I will give it a day or so

Comment: It appears you have gone through all the steps correctly. 
As per [OAuth API Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) adding a restricted scope might take **4-8 weeks** to verify by Google. That is with a responsive developer, which you seem to be. So it seems you have to give it some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that Google was correct and the scopes the app was submitting is incorrect.

**What was approved by google:**

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly

**But the app was requesting:**

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

Almost the same, but not. Always triple check that what you are sending is the same as what is allowed.